# What do (n&(n-1))==0 and n&(n-1)==0 do in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

What do `(n&(n-1))==0` and `n&(n-1)==0` do (`n` is an integer) in C++?

```
if ((n&(n-1))==0)
{
    // do something
}

if (n&(n-1)==0)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Did you look up the meaning of `&`? If not, why not?

Comment: I already feel sorry for the maintainer of this software

Comment: Big warning, the operator& has a lower priority than operator==. First condition test for power of two value but second line does not as it is equal to 'n & ( n-1==0 )'. Also, that kind of test should be in an utility function with a meangful name like IsPowerOfTwo

Comment: @galop1n or more accurately, `IsPowerOfTwoOrZero`

Comment: `n & (n - 1) == 0` is equivalent to `n & ((n -1) == 0)` and so `n == 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `(n & (n - 1)) == 0`:

`n & (n - 1)` unset the lower set bit of `n`
in binary: `XXX10000` -> `XXX00000`

So `(n & (n - 1)) == 0` for `0` and all powers of `2`.

### `n & (n - 1) == 0`:

`n & (n - 1) == 0` is equivalent to `n & ((n - 1) == 0)` (due to precedence of operator) and so `n == 1`.

Answer (score 13):

They are suppose to test if the number `n` is a power of 2 (although the second one fails to do so as mentioned in the comment). It is based on a simple observation that in binary representation powers of 2 are the only numbers with just one bit set to `1`. If you subtract `1` from such number you get a sequence of `1`s.

**Example (positive):**

```
n = 32
```

than in binary representation

```
n = 100000
```

Then 
    n - 1 = 011111
So if you take `n - 1 & n` you get `0`.

**Example (negative):**

```
n = 6
```

than in binary representation

```
n = 110
```

Now

```
n - 1 = 101
```

So `((n - 1) & n) == 100 > 0`.

Note, that, as @harold mentioned in his comment, `0` will also pass this test.

Comment: They are not the same. Precedence of `&` is lower than `==`.

Comment: Sure, sorry, the second one is *"wrong"* and in the end just checks if the number is equal to 1. Exactly by the argument you gave here.

Answer (score 0):

As Lukaszz Said,

it checks whether number n is power of two or not.

Explanation :-

if n = 3 or any other number which is not power of 2

(n = 3, So (n-1) = 2)

3 :- 0000 0011
2 :- 0000 0010

than AND operation :- 0000 0010

if n = 2 or any other number which is power of two

(n = 2 so (n-1) = 1)
2 :- 0000 0010
1 :- 0000 0001

than AND Operation :- 0000 0000

So if the number is power of two it always returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to check for the power of two as follows ::

```
bool isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
    return!(n&n-1)*n>0;
}
```