# How could I determine the worst case in this code?

Tags: algorithm, analysis

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        
    if((i&(i-1))==0) {      
        
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {
            f();
        }
    } else {
        f();
    }
    
}
```

I did some test cases of this code and when i = 2^(i-1) the second for is executed, how could I determinate the big O notation, I think it could be O(n^2). f() is O(1), and how could I get the amortized analysis

Comment: amortized analysis for which operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `i` is a power of `2`, the inner loop performs exactly `i` calls to `f`. Otherwise, there is a single call.

If `n` is a power of `2`, let `2^m`, we have a total of

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... n + n - m
```

calls and this is

```
3n - 1 - lg(n).
```

On average (per iteration of the main loop), this is asymptotic to `3`.

---

Now if `n = 2^m + n'` with `n' < 2^m`, the count is

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^m + 2^m + n' - m = 3.2^m - 1 + n' - m = 3.n - 2.n' - 1 - Lg(n - n')
```

which is still amortized `3` at worse but goes down to `2` for some n.

Answer (score 1):

Consider when `(i&(i-1)) == 0`. It is just true for powers of 2 (more details see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21235132/3768871)). How many powers of 2 is existing less than `n`? `log(n)`. For `log(n)` cases, iterates the second loop for `i` times, and for remaining the cost is `Theta(1)`. Hence, the time complexity is (w.l.o.g. suppose `n` is the power of 2):

```
T(n) = n - log(n) // for i != 2^k
       + (1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^{log(n)}) // for i = 2^k
     = n - log(n) + 2^{log(n)+1} - 1 = 3n - log(n) - 1 = Theta(n) // 2^log(n) = n
```

Hence `T(n) = Theta(n)`.

Comment: the amortized cost would then be 3?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is n.

The expression `( i & ( i - 1 ) ) == 0 )` is only evaluates to true when i is a power of 2. Therefore, it will execute log2( n ) times.

Next step is finding how many times f is called from the inner loop. `i` values are powers of 2, their sum is called "geometric series", wikipedia [has the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series).

Dropping some constants, the geometric sum is proportional to 2^N where N is count of elements in the series. In your case, the count is log2( n ), 2^log2( n ) == n.

The `else` block will also be called O(n) times.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually tested this out, and it makes sense that it's `n`, since you're hitting that powers of 2 at a rate of log(n) but each time you hit one it explodes the ouput by 2^n. When it's not a power of 2, it's just n as well.

Here's what I ran:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int n = 1000000;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            
        if((i&(i-1))==0){       
            
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
                count++;
                std::cout << i << "," << j << ":" << count << std::endl;
            }
        }else{
                count++;
                std::cout << i << ":" << count << std::endl;
        }
    
}}
```

For selected values:

`10:21`

`100:220`

`1000:2013`

`10000:26369`

`100000:231054`

`1000000:2048555`

I'm not saying that running the program is the definitive answer, just that it's a useful check that you're not completely off (eg if it was n^2 or constant time). As you can see, each time you 10x the input, it more or less does that that to the output. If it was n^2 the last line would be 10^10 as big as the first. If it was constant it would be a similar number as the first. nlogn about 1.1M times.